# Как отделить некоторые элементы от полученого значения в response?

Tags: python

Я получаю такой response:

```
$13.94 USD
```

От него необходимо получить только цифры. Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 3):

Пример:

```
In [15]: response = "$13.94 USD"

In [16]: import re

In [17]: res = re.sub(r"[^\d\.]", "", response)

In [18]: print(res)
13.94
```

Comment: Это будет в интегере?

Comment: @gisi24, `"в интегере"` ???

Comment: то есть в int??

Comment: @gisi24, что вы хотите получить в итоге `13` или `14`?

Comment: Очевидно, что 13.94 не может быть «в интегере». Это будет в строке.